# How to get Datatable row value and map it to another Datatable?

Tags: sql, datatables

I'm a newby in DataTables and I have a challenge right now on how to map the ID of my first table to my second table.

This is my sample table:

```
First Table
P_ID   |  Desc   | Unit
A.1    | Samp1   | SampUnit1
A.2    | Samp1   | SampUnit1

Second Table
S_ID   |  Desc   | Unit
A.1(a)  | Sub1   | Sub1
```

What I need is to map A.1 to A.1(a), because currently my script loads A.1(a) to both A.1 and A.2.

Answer (score 0):

Got the correct answer by adding new column for Parent ID.